# Keras load model after saving makes random predictions in a new python session

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using tensorflow version '2.0.0' and keras version '2.3.0' to develop the model. Here's how I saved the model:

```
seed = 1234
random.seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
tf.compat.v1.random.set_random_seed(seed)
```

I then save the entire model as instructed [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize):

```
model.save('some_model_name.h5')
```

I am getting an accuracy of about 95% during training. When I load the model from a different python session, like:

```
# Recreate the exact same model
new_model = load_model('some_model_name.h5', custom_objects={'SeqSelfAttention': SeqSelfAttention})
score = new_model.evaluate([x_img_train, x_txt_train], y_train, verbose=2)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (new_model.metrics_names[1], score[1]*100))
```

The accuracy now is about 4%. Please note that I have batch norm and dropout layers. How can I make the predictions of my model consistent across different sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I have downgraded the TensorFlow version to 1.13.1, owing to stability issues of 2.0.0.

Secondly, I had to ensure a few things before I could achieve some level of reproducibility:

1. Use Adagrad optimizer instead of Adam gave me performance comparable to the train session. When every time I loaded the session, it was giving me a high variance in the predictions (for Adam)
2. Loading architecture from json and loading model weights subsequently gave me different results as compared to saving and loading weights only. The former approach seemed to produce comparable performance (to training)
3. Using tf.session to train and saving it and reloading the tf.session in a new python session did the trick.

There is no variation in the results with or without dropouts or Batch norm.

Please note that following these steps gave me some level of consistency although it's not 100% reproducible. If you're facing a similar issue, perhaps these insights could help.

Answer (score -1):

After loading the model in a new kernel instance, make sure to config losses and metrics again with .compile() in the same way you did before saving.

For example:

```
old_model = tf.keras.Sequential([ ... ])
old_model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'sgd', metrics = ['accuracy'])
old_model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=valid_ds, epochs=3)
old_model.evaluate(test_ds)
old_model.save('some_model_name.h5')
```

Then in the new kernel:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
new_model = load_model("some_model_name.h5")
new_model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'sgd', metrics = ['accuracy'])
new_model.evaluate(test_ds) # should be the same now
```

Comment: This is false.  compile trains the model which will yield different predictions since training relies on randomness to start.  However, that doesn't address the main issue, which is training a model and re-loading the same trained model.  Its a plausable use case that some network can take 10 hours to train, and it would be nice to train it once, save it, test it against a test set, save it, reload it, re-test it against the same test set, and have it yield the same predictions verifying the save/load cycle didnt alter the network.